# cant move focus to the control jQuery 1.7 ie8

Tags: jquery, mobile, internet-explorer-8

I am having problems with a browser compatibility issue with jQuery Mobile and jQuery 1.7.

On this site www.carpaholics.com all works fine in most browsers we are not supporting IE7 but do need to support ie8.

If I switch the jquery that is loaded to 1.6.4 I do get some content loaded which I could then apply stying fixes to but we do need to be able to use jQuery 1.7

When the site is loaded with jQuery 1.7 I get a 'Can't move focus to the control because it is invisible...' error.

But I can't for the life of me sus out what is causing the problem. I am sure it is not jQuery 1.7 itself that is incompatible with ie8 and I dont think it is jQuery mobile (although on jQm site they do use 1.6.4 rather than 1.7)

So does anyone know the first steps I can take to working out what the problem here?

Or does anyone know whether it is possible to get jQuery mobile working with jQuery 1.7 cross browser?

Any ideas most welcome...

Comment: Just out of curiosity why use 1.7 when 1.7.1 has been released?  I'm fairly positive I read it fixed several bugs (don't remember if any were related to what you have though).

Comment: Which version of jQuery Mobile? 1.0.0 was meant to be used with jQuery 1.6 but 1.0.1 should be usable with jQuery 1.7. I know the specific bug you're describing has been fixed since 1.0.

Comment: unfortunately the problem still persists with 1.0.1 ...:(

Comment: Have posted the issue and a solution on Github [link](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/3505)

Answer (score 1):

I had to mess with this same issue today. As best as I can tell from my research and experimentation, jQuery Mobile 1.0.1 and earlier require jQuery Core 1.6.4 and will not work with 1.7 or higher in IE8. This is apparently due to a change in how exception handling in the jQuery 1.7 line, and also that IE throws an exception in this instance when other browsers do not.

The recently released (as of April 13th) jQuery Mobile 1.1 does officially support jQuery Core 1.7.1 (or 1.6.4 if you prefer).

So it sounds like you need to upgrade to jQuery Mobile 1.1.

Or if you're really committed to the version mismatch, you may be able to add some of your own `try..catch` blocks into jQuery Mobile 1.0 (for example; I found some limited success by adding them to the `reFocus( page )` function). But once you customize jQM, you're on your own...